# Twitter API Authenticate vs Authorize

Tags: api, twitter, oauth, authorization, twitter-oauth

Hi all could you just tell what is the difference between Twitter Authenticate and Authorize

```
$twitterConnect = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
$twitterToken = $twitterConnect->getRequestToken();

$redirect_url = $twitterConnect->getAuthorizeURL($twitterToken, true); // authenticate 
$redirect_url = $twitterConnect->getAuthorizeURL($twitterToken, false); //authorize
```

Answer (score 19):

With `oauth/authenticate` if the user is signed into twitter.com and has previously authorized the application to access their account they will be silently redirected back to the app.

With `oauth/authorize` the user will see the allow screen regardless if they have previously authorized the app.

Comment: You are my life saver. :)

Answer (score 1):

> This method differs from GET oauth / authorize in that if the user has already granted the application permission, the redirect will occur without the user having to re-approve the application.
>
> https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/get/oauth/authenticate

Note:

1. You must enable "Sign in with Twitter" in the application settings to achieve this.
2. Desktop applications must use this authorize and not authenticate.